# Angular 2 circular components

Tags: angular

I try to get circular dependent components working in angular2. What works so far out of the box is recursive components (which did not work that easily in angular1):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ace-view',
    template:
`<ace-view *ngFor="let SubView of SubViews" [view]="SubView"></ace-view>`,
    directives:[
        AceViewComponent
    ]
})
export class AceViewComponent {
...
}
```

The component shown above uses itself for sub-Views, which works as expected.

However, I have a situation where component A needs component B and component B needs Component A:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ace-A',
    template:
`<ace-B *ngIf="whatever"></ace-B>`,
    directives:[
        AceB
    ]
})
export class AceA {}


@Component({
    selector: 'ace-B',
    template:
`<ace-A *ngIf="whatever"></ace-A>`,
    directives:[
        AceA
    ]
})
export class AceB {}
```

Then the problem is, that AceB is not yet defined, when used in directives of AceA. Even worse, AceA and AceB might be in different files.

- What is the correct solution for this kind of recurrences?
- Can I somehow add a directive to the directives array later at runtime?
- Where can I find the source code of the @component decorator and its implementation (so that I can see what it does and try to mimic it at runtime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would leverage `forwardRef` for this use case. As a matter of fact ES6 classes don't support hoisting.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ace-A',
  template: `
    <ace-B *ngIf="whatever"></ace-B>
  `,
  directives:[
    forwardRef(() => AceB)
  ]
})
export class AceA {}

(...)
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! And it works, I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: Still, could you say something about adding additional directives at runtime?

Comment: You're welcome! I think that it's the same since the problem is to reference a type that isn't created yet ;-)

Comment: Thank you, will give that a try. Now when I split the components AceA and AceB into 2 files, of course AceB cannot be imported in AceA, because of circular dependency problem. Is the solution to define an interface for AceB and pointing to this?

Comment: Ok, seems to work: Just use forwardRef in both components and do the circular import (means FileA imports FileB and FileB imports FileA). Doing this assures that TypeScript compiler is satisfied and firwardRef assures, that it also works at runtime. I use forwardRef on both directives because it may be kinda randiom, which File gets loaded first...
Maybe you want to include that piece of information in your answer to conserve it for others.

Comment: directives is no more a valid attribute of @Component, right?

Comment: @OlivierAmblet Nope, but you can register it as a provider instead:  providers: [{
            provide: AceB,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => AceB),
            multi: true
        }]